# Append id with the ngModel

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

When looping over the the scope variable `extra` I am getting the id using `item.id`. Now I want to append the `item.id` with `BookingConfirmationFormsState` so it becomes e.g. `BookingConfirmationFormsState35`

When I run the following code I get an error

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property '35' of undefined
```

The following is what I am currently working with.

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="ContinueBookingConfirmation()">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of extra" class="row-extra" id="extra-item-{{ item.id }}">
        <ion-col width-10>
            <ion-checkbox class="switcher display-block" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="BookingConfirmationFormsState[item.id]" name="checkbox" [checked]="true"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-67 class="description">{{ item.description }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col width-23 style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="rate text-center display-block">FJ ${{ item.rate }}</div>
            <div class="qty text-center display-block"><input type="number" min="1" max="100" class="text-center" [(ngModel)]="BookingConfirmationFormsQty[item.id]" name="qty" /></div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-col width-100 class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="continue">Continue</button></ion-col>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class BookingEnhancementPage {
  BookingConfirmationFormsState35: string;
  BookingConfirmationFormsState36: string;
  BookingConfirmationFormsState37: string;

  BookingConfirmationFormsQty35: number;
  BookingConfirmationFormsQty36: number;
  BookingConfirmationFormsQty37: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {}

  ContinueBookingConfirmation(){
    console.log( this.BookingConfirmationFormsState35 );
    console.log( this.BookingConfirmationFormsState36 );
    console.log( this.BookingConfirmationFormsState37 );
  }

}
```

Comment: I think `BookingConfirmationFormsState[item.id]` is being treated as (item.id)th element of the array BookingConfirmationFormsState. Try appending it as string `BookingConfirmationFormsState+item.id`

Comment: @AvantikaSaini thanks but still doesn't work. Any other idea?

Comment: Did you try changing both `BookingConfirmationFormsQty[item.id]` and `BookingConfirmationFormsState[item.id]` to `BookingConfirmationFormsQty+item.id` and `BookingConfirmationFormsState+item.id` ? In my opinion, it should have worked